# how to push all elements of array in variable key in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to push all the value of the array in the mongodb.
when I try to push a single value, the following code is working.

```
var query = {};
query["username"] = "abc";
query["movie._id"] = new ObjectId("56e62ebc56c69a6716cdc305");

var datatopush = "this is a photo";

var event = {};
event["movie.$.photo"] = datatopush;

UserEventsDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
 query,{
    "$push": event
}
,function(err,user){
   if(!err) res.send("done");
   else res.send(err);
});
});
```

But if   datatopush = ["a","b"];
How to push all these value in the mongodb.
How to use $each in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) like this:

```
event["movie.$.photo"] = { "$each": datatopush };
```

Which makes the context:

```
{ "$push": { "movie.$.photo": { "$each": datatopush } } }
```